# How to protect ASP.NET MVC/IIS application from copying?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We are developing intranet base solution in ASP.NET MVC. It will be deployed across client's own internal network hence respective employee of client can use it.

As it is IIS based intranet application, one can easily copy files and configure IIS on other server. So what are the different solution available to prevent this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you are publishing the ASP.NET MVC web app, you can publish the version in dlls.

So Instead of creating a single Web App, you can create a new dll file where you are going to compile all the Models of the App and save it in a dll).

Then coming back to your original solution you will add the reference to this dll so no logic can be taken of your solution.

Comment: Jose - what I understood is that he is asking for how to prevent client from configuring application on other server i.e. some kind of new unlock key is needed if client just copy past file from virtual directory to another server hence stopping client to sale it to another party... this is what I understood because.. I came across such scenario few time

Comment: In that case can create a method that request a password when the application 1st run the app before loading it. It should run the action in the Global.asax.cs file. after the bundleconfig line

Comment: but where to store that password so that it do not work on new database, server while just copy/paste db/web files to new server?